# Form and PHP function to save form data to mysql in same file

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I have been trying to sort this out but so far I haven't been able to get it to work. No errors are thrown, the page refreshes on submit. I am at a loss, but I am not exactly an expert, fairly new to this.

Here is the code (simplified for posting):

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo              "<!-- Form starts here -->
                  <form id=\"billing\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
                  <!-- Name -->
                  <div class=\"control-group\">
                  <label class=\"control-label\"><b>Name</b></label>
                  <div class=\"controls\">
                  <input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"name\" placeholder=\"your name\" class=\"input-large\">
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Zip -->
                  <div class=\"control-group\">
                  <label class=\"control-label\"><b>Zip Code</b></label>
                  <div class=\"controls\">
                  <input type=\"text\" id=\"billingzip\" name=\"billingzip\" placeholder=\"5 digit zip\" class=\"input-large\">
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Submit -->
                  <div class=\"control-group\">
                  <div class=\"controls\">
                  <button class=\"button save small_green_button\" type=\"submit\">
                  &nbsp;Save&nbsp;
                  </button>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>";
}
else
{
 $host="localhost";
 $user_name="user";
 $pwd="password";
 $database_name="database";
 $db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
 $dbsel=mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);

 if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
               if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";

                   $account_id = users::getAttr('Account', 'account_id'); 
                   $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['billingzip']);
                   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

                           $sql = "INSERT INTO `billing`
                                   SET `account_id` = '{$account_id}',
                                       `zip` = '{$billingzip}',
                                       `name` = '{$name}',
                                       `updated_at` = NOW()";

                           $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbsel) 
                                or  die(mysql_error().$sql);

                 mysql_close($db);


   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Don't write new code with the `mysql_*` functions, especially when you are learning it. They are in the process of becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Learn with `mysqli_*` or PDO right away.

Comment: `{$billingzip}` should be `{$zip}`, and if `$account_id` is a numerical value you don't need the quotes in the query around it. Not sure  though if that would result in an invalid query.

Comment: I don't see any input named `submit` in your form.

Comment: I left it out of the paste by accident, but it is in there.

Comment: `type="submit"` is not `name="submit"`

Answer (score 1):

First what i see is

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbsel) or  die(mysql_error().$sql);
```

In my opinion you should wrote:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or  die(mysql_error().$sql);
```

Comment: I tried that exact method and it did not work.  I realized the database name wasn't being referenced so I added **dbsel** to reference it.

Comment: OK, so your sql syntax is wrong ? I know is this should be like  INSERT INTO table_name ([columns]) VALUES ([values])  | http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: This `INSERT` syntax is valid.

Comment: @Arringar1 `$dbsel` is definitely wrong, you must reference `$db` (or leave it out, it's not nessecary when you have only one database connection).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize my comments:

Your form does not have any form element with `name="submit"`, so `(!isset($_POST['submit']))` will always be `true` and your `else` block will never execute. You can check this by adding `var_dump($_POST);` to the beginning of your script (before the `if` clause). `var_dump()` is one of the best debugging tools you have with PHP. Use it.

```
$dbsel=mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
```

will return either `true` or `false`, so `$dbsel` will always be one of these two values. You don't need to store it, you can just add your `or die("cannot select database");`.

```
$account_id = users::getAttr('Account', 'account_id');
```

You have no information what this returns. It matters later if `$account_id` contains a numerical id or a string. If it is a string it is okay, if it is a numerical value you should change this:

```
`account_id` = {$account_id}
```

Next:

```
`zip` = '{$billingzip}',
```

You stored `$_POST['billingzip']` in `$zip`, so this should be this:

```
`zip` = '{$zip}',
```

Last, but not least:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbsel)
```

As stated earlier, `$dbsel` either contains `true` or `false`, so it is wrong here, it should be the `$db` reference. Also, since you don't work with multiple database connections you don't need to reference any at all here.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql /* , $db */)
```

And the usual advice concerning mysql questions: If you write new code don't use the `mysql_*` functions at all. They are in the process of becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Learn with `mysqli_*` or PDO right away. Both methods allow you to use prepared statements, which allows you to make sure your site is safe from SQL injections without having you to bother with escaping user provided content.

Do yourself a favor, comment the complete block out and rewrite it with PDO or `mysqli_*`.